# Dynamic indexing through dot notation in liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm been trying to find a way to do this but haven't had any luck.

I'm using Metafields to store information by customer id. As a result, in order to extract the information for each customer I would like to be able to pull it using something like

```
{% if shop.metafields.{customer.id} %}
```

Is this an acceptable way to access my metafield with the key that is equal to the value of the customer.id when the customer is signed in?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a metafield that belongs to the logged in customer then you can do that like this:

```
{% if customer %}
    {{ customer.metafields.inventory.warehouse }}
{% endif %}
```

Where `inventory` is the metafield namespace and `warehouse` is the metafield key. You can find more examples of the syntax here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield

Comment: Hmm see I was hoping to specify the key dynamically. Any thoughts on how I might do that?

Comment: You could do something like this - let me know if this is not what you meant:
`{% assign metafield_key = 'warehouse' %}`
`{{ customer.metafields.inventory[metafield_key] }}`

Comment: Interesting. So I would have to pull the customer id by assigning it to another variable, then print that into my dot notation. I'll give it a try!